# How would you handle different error responses for different routes using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

I have Laravel routes set up as the example below shows:

```
Route::group(array('domain' => 'example.com'), function()
{
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'root.index', 'uses' => 'RootController@Index'));
    [...]
});

Route::group(array('domain' => 'api.example.com'), function()
{
    Route::when('*', 'ApiFilter');
    Route::get('/', array('as' => 'api.index', 'uses' => 'ApiController@Index'));
    [...]
});
```

Now, when it comes to responding to requests with errors (such as 404, 403, 500 etc) Laravel provides a great solution using `App::error` and its related methods.

I would like to respond to errors differently depending on whether the request is for the root or api domain.

Can I do this using `App::error`?

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do this. Just need to get the request object from the `$exception` object in the exception handler, for example, if you have an exception handler like this:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    $request = $exception->getTrace()[0]['args'][0];
    $path = $request->path(); // will return path without domain, i.e. user/1
    // Take some action depending on the $path
});
```

Now depending on the path you may take an action. You may use any public method of `Request` class, such as `if($request->is('admin/*'))` or `$request->url()` to get full url with domain.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use content negotiation (`Accept` request header or URLs suffixed by `.json` / `.xml`) for different error formatting, like so:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    if (!preg_match("@text/html@", Request::header('Accept')))
    {
        return Response::json
        (
            array("error" => array("message" => $exception->getMessage())),
            $code
        );
    }
});
```

This would result in errors being returned as JSON, if request header `Accept` would not contain `text/html`.

So.. if you would go to api.yoursite.com with your browser - you would still see the default HTML error page with stack-trace and full details, because browser will send `Accept: text/html`.

Otherwise, if `Accept` header is not set or does not explicitly contain `text/html` - error will be formatted as JSON.

Alternatively, instead of `preg_match` you could use `Request::wantsJson()` for detecting requested content format.

Or if you absolutely need/want to separate API logics and go via sub-domain route..:

```
App::error(function(Exception $exception, $code)
{
    if (preg_match("@^https?://api\.@", Request::url())) /* Or, if not using sub-domain: Request:is("api/*") */
    {
        return Response::json
        (
            array("error" => array("message" => $exception->getMessage())),
            $code
        );
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would apply separate filters to each route group, then specify error handling events in each filter.

Comment: Do you have an example of how you apply error handlers to route groups?